# Use Python to read the LAST fifth line whose number of lines larger than 40000

Tags: python

I use the following Python codes to read the last Third line from a text file. It has more than 40000 lines:

```
my_file1.close()
  with open (L[i],"r") as my_file3:
     for line in my_file3:
        if line.strip():
           count+=1
count=count-5
print (count)
with open (L[i],"r") as my_file3:
   lines=my_file3.readlines()
     temp=lines[count].split()
     cpu[i]=temp[4]
        pht[i]=temp[1]
```

The IDLE told me "IndexError: list index out of range". Anyone can give me a favor?

Comment: At which line of your code does this error happen?

Comment: temp=lines[count].split(). This one.

Comment: I think it is because that count is too large. It is 40000.

Comment: Why this: `count=count-5`? Why `5`?

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong, even disregarding the bug you're asking about. `count` will contain the number of non-empty lines in the file, but taking `count-5` will **not** give you the fifth last non-empty line in the file. It will give you the `5+n`-th last line in the file, where `n` is the number of empty lines. This might as well be an empty line.

Comment: In fact, this could be the cause of the bug. You're calling `split()` on an empty line, so `temp` is a zero-length list. It's hard to know for sure without knowing your input file, and which line exactly the `IndexError` occurs on. I.e. whether it's `lines[count]` or `temp[1]` or `temp[4]`. Or even `cpu[i]` or `pht[i]`! You never show us those.

Comment: **tl;dr** You need to tell us, at least, which of those **five** list accesses is throwing, and what the contents of that list are at that point. Preferably using some sort of simple, readable dummy data.

Comment: Have you tried this on a file with 10 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain why you use `strip()`. To get the 5th last line, use:

```
lines = open("in.txt").readlines()
line = lines[-5]
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the correct straightforward way to get the fifth last nonempty line from a file would be:

```
lines = [l for l in my_file where l.strip()]
temp = lines[-5].split()
```

(You could get rid of the memory overhead using less straightforward code, but that's tangential for now.)

If this doesn't get rid of your bug, the problem is in the line not having enough space-separated tokens in it, or in `cpu` or `pht` not having `i` elements.